# GitHub pages not loading

Tags: html, github

I uploaded my webpage to a repository and used the pages function to upload the webpage, and I got a URL which I shared to my friend, and teacher. They can access it, but I cannot; the page just loads and just shows the following [GitHub pages, unable to access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnPjW.png)
here is my URL: https://nyanlinsett.github.io/Color-Therapy/

Comment: are you using some proxy or vpn for your web browsing? it appears to work fine for me also

Comment: Nop. I'm not using anything!

Answer (score 0):

try flush your DNS cache.

Run the following command in cmd;

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```